# Adding a new column to a spark dataframe which is the sum of the columns works fine inside pyspark shell but not on the cluster

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to add a new column to a pyspark dataframe and the new column is derived as the sum of some of the columns of the dataframe:

The list **new_cols** contains the list of columns to be summed.

```
  big_df = big_df.withColumn('voice volume from 3G-fixated users',sum(big_df[c] for c in new_cols))
```

This works perfectly fine inside pyspark shell.

This is part of the much bigger code , which I am not pasting here.

But when I try and submit my file on the cluster with the following parameters:

```
 nohup spark-submit  --conf spark.network.timeout=3600s --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster --executor-memory 40g --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 8 --driver-memory 20g  --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar  --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml  --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=3600s recombinate_new_spark.py &
```

It fails with the below error:

```
Log Type: stdout

Log Upload Time: Mon Jul 24 21:49:21 -0400 2017
Log Length: 7218
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "recombinate_new_spark.py", line 114, in <module>
big_df = big_df.withColumn('3G-fixated voice users',sum(big_df[c] for c in new_cols))
File "/opt/data/data04/yarn/local/usercache/vb4320/appcache/application_1500830506843_32979/container_e712_1500830506843_32979_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 39, in _
 File "/opt/data/data04/yarn/local/usercache/vb4320/appcache/application_1500830506843_32979/container_e712_1500830506843_32979_01_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 804, in __call__
File "/opt/data/data04/yarn/local/usercache/vb4320/appcache/application_1500830506843_32979/container_e712_1500830506843_32979_01_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 278, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Having a hard time debugging this as it works fine inside the pyspark shell with the exact same size of data that is being submitted to be processed on cluster.

Thanks in advance for any tips and help.

Comment: Using **from pyspark.sql import functions as f** instead of **from pyspark.sql.functions import \* **

Comment: I don't think I followed. For this one I am not using SQL functions. Possible to elaborate what you are trying to say?